# Relationship between R squared and F-Test under heteroskedasicity

Tags: econometrics

I have a question regarding the Relationship between R squared and F-Test under heteroskedasicity.

If R squared is uaffected by the heteroskedasicity, since it is a population estimate, then why is F-stats invaild, because F-test can be conducted using R squared.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand now, after reading Textbook. R squared = 1 - var(u)/var(X), however, under heteroskedastic error, these two estimate are not vaild for finite sample distribution, as the estimated error variance are not vaild in this case.